# GAE Datastore: Performance of querying the same StringListProperty with multiple equalities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Assuming I have a model

```
class MyModelList(db.Model):
  listed_props = db.StringListProperty(indexed=True)
```

and I query it with

```
SELECT * from MyModelList where listed_props = 'a' and listed_props = 'b'
```

will it be almost as performant (latency wise) as if I had a model

```
class MyModelProps(db.Model):
  property_1 = db.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  property_2 = db.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```

which I would query with:

```
SELECT * from MyModelProps where property_1 = 'a' and property_2 = 'b'
```

and a composite index of

```
indexes:
- kind: MyModelProps
   properties:
   - name: property_1
   - name: property_2
```

The query for the first example with MyModelList seems harder to answer because the datastore will have to merge the listed_props index with itself (I assume 2 binary searches to find the start and then merging the indexes) compared to the second example (I assume 1 binary search to find the start and then just read).

This will be especially complicated if the index of MyModelList.listed_props needs to be sharded across multiple bigtable tablets.

Can I expect about the same performance (latency wise) for the two?

PS: The reason I'm asking is because I'd love to go with MyModelList.listed_props as it is much cheaper to update existing entities because I could get rid of a lot of composite indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise it is a very bad idea to do queries without composite indexes like

```
SELECT * from MyModelList where listed_props = 'a' and listed_props = 'b'
```

It is much more performant if you do

```
SELECT * from MyModelProps where property_1 = 'a' and property_2 = 'b'
```

with a composite index, even if it doesn't need one.

I've implemented both solutions and ran it in a live system with 2.7 million records. The one with composite index was about 100x faster.

There is a fantastic article that explains it all:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/01/An-App-Engine-limitation-you-didn-t-know-about